how to integrate tauri v2 with flutter web using dart js_interop?
I'm evaluating the newly released Tauri v2 framework which allows to write a desktop/mobile app in Rust with a UI in JavaScript, but I would like to use Flutter Web as the UI. I'm trying to use the recently released dart js_interop package, but even though I manage to see the web UI showing up, I can't make any invocations to Tauri. I tried setting withGlobalTauri: true on the tauri configuration -or- use npm packages but I can't make them work.
(I'm aware Flutter can be used to mobile and desktop apps and also that there are other integration methods with flutter and rust, I just wanted to see if it was possible to use Tauri with Flutter web as the UI rendering)
Anybody knows how to write the dart js_interop definition to call window.__TAURI__.core.invoke(..) from the Tauri API?
I tried multiple variants, I think the closest I got was when using:
import 'dart:js_interop';

@JS('window.__TAURI__.core.invoke')
external JSString invoke(JSString command);

and tried to call:
String cmd() {
  return invoke('cmd'.toJS).toDart;
}


But that returns an error saying:
TypeError: Instance of 'LegacyJavaScriptObject': type 'LegacyJavaScriptObject' is not a subtype of type 'String'.

Thanks!

does your cmd command return a string?

@kmdreko yes. the body of the method is just String::from("hello world")
